getting error message 'An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.'
i want to run with headless mode in appium by javascript, after running it when emulator is running, just passed first test and after that another test wont passed and it can not find any elements.
const Page = require('./page');

/**
 * Sub-page containing specific selectors and methods for login
 */
class Forgetpage extends Page {

    get allowbutton () {
        return $('android.widget.Button')
        
    }

    get forget () {
        
        return $('android.view.View');
        
    }
    
    get inputemail () {
        return $('android.widget.EditText');
        
    }

    get btnSubmit () {
        return $('//android.view.View[@content-desc="Continue"]');
    }

    
    async forgetpass(email) {
        
        await this.allowbutton.click();
        await this.forget.click()
        // await this.inputemail.click()
        // await this.inputemail.setValue(email)
    }

    /**
     * Method to open the mobile app
     */
    open () {
        return super.openApp(); // This method is defined in the base Page class
    }
}



module.exports = new Forgetpage();


2024-09-30T06:01:04.245Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("00000000-0000-034d-ffff-ffff0000002e")
[0-0] 2024-09-30T06:01:04.245Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/session/b85e9dd4-78da-43b4-a4cf-ac1d74e87a60/element/00000000-0000-034d-ffff-ffff0000002e/click
[0-0] 2024-09-30T06:01:05.027Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null
[0-0] 2024-09-30T06:01:05.028Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("class name", "android.view.View")
[0-0] 2024-09-30T06:01:05.028Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/session/b85e9dd4-78da-43b4-a4cf-ac1d74e87a60/element
[0-0] 2024-09-30T06:01:05.028Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'class name', value: 'android.view.View' }
[0-0] 2024-09-30T06:01:05.779Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
[0-0]   error: 'no such element',
[0-0]   message: 'An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.',
[0-0]   stacktrace: 'NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.\n' +
[0-0]     '    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrEls (C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\appium_Webdriver\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-driver\\node_modules\\appium-android-driver\\lib\\commands\\find.ts:86:11)\n' +        
[0-0]     '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
[0-0]     '    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrElsWithProcessing (C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\appium_Webdriver\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-driver\\node_modules\\@appium\\base-driver\\lib\\basedriver\\commands\\find.ts:60:12)\n' +
[0-0]     '    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElement (C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\appium_Webdriver\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-driver\\node_modules\\@appium\\base-driver\\lib\\basedriver\\commands\\find.ts:75:12)'
[0-0] }

